# Adding extra time to the time column before showing query results in PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, web

So I have a table which has the Bus name and time. Based on this query this will list the name of the bus and time depending on what the user input is. Now in my database the first bus arrives at 11:00 am but this may have a delay of 2 minutes depending on its last journey it has taken. Would I need to create a time variable and concatenate that with the time column within my query in order for it to show an arrival time of 11:02 am

Comment: what is the type of `dt.time`? timestamp? time? text?

Comment: In my PostgreSQL database I have column name called "time" with the Data type as "time without time zone". The times were entered manually within my database. @Nordenheim

Comment: have you tried `dt.time + interval '2 minutes' as time` or select it separately? I think this might be your answer

Comment: That's worked @Nordenheim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `interval`:

```
SELECT dt.name as name, dt.time + interval '2 minutes' as time
```

Or select it separately:

```
SELECT
    dt.name as name,
    dt.time as time,
    dt.time + interval '2 minutes' as addedTime
```